# Miscellaneous range of stat_smooth()

Tags: r, ggplot2, range, data-fitting

The `ggplot2`-function `stat_smooth()` has the option `fullrange=TRUE` or `FALSE` which decides if the fit is drawn over the range of the data or the range of the graph.

Is there a way to give the `stat_smooth()` a miscellaneous range ? E.g. if my plot has x in (0,100) but the fitted data x in (40,60), to plot the smoothed fit for range x in (30,70).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `xseq` in your `stat_smooth` call as follows:

```
stat_smooth(xseq = seq(30,70, length=80))
```

@ Hadley: Why are `xseq`, and `n` as plotting-Parameters not documented in `?geom_smooth`? See here for the source-code: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-smooth.r

**Example:** (Addapted from `?geom_smooth`)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(c(10,30)) + 
  stat_smooth(method=lm, fullrange = TRUE, xseq = seq(11,25, length=80))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great ! What is the purpose of `length=80` ?

Comment: Try `xseq = c(11,25)` and see the difference in the CI.I guess 80 steps of prediction-points produces a reasonable good graphical output. `length = 80` is hadley's (so ggplot's) standard.